# How to connect or make connection between a React App and a Rasbperry Pi 4?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, raspberry-pi4

Hello i am working on sending orders and receiving live video feed between a tablet and a rasberry pi4. What is the best approach and things i would need to use in order to accomplish this. The order must be sent from the tablet to make the pi4 turn on cameras.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For communication between raspberry pi4 and a mobile, you can use `Bluetooth` and can use this module.

https://polidea.github.io/react-native-ble-plx/

here is an example.

https://itnext.io/using-a-raspberry-pi-to-control-leds-part-iii-react-native-app-29ee3f4afb8c

Comment: Can i not use wifi to send orders? If my pi is connected to my local network and i know the IP address.